# execute 'Goyo' on loading pandoc document

Tags: neovim, filetype, plugin-vim-pandoc

It seems like running the Goyo command (a distraction free editing plugin) on loading a pandoc document should be really simple, but

```
execute "Goyo"
```

in `.config/nvim/ftplugin/pandoc.vim` leads the shell to produce the error

```
“nvim test.md” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

The filetype is correctly detected (`echo 'hello'` works), but for some reason it doesn't like executing Goyo. I think the problem is that Goyo is being executed before the buffer is fully loaded, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Couple of tips: (1) you don’t need execute—`Goyo` alone will do the trick; (2) consider checking the command exists before calling it; (3) consider putting your script in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/pandoc.vim` so you don’t override the vim runtime files. But I can’t tell you why that particular command is failing; have you searched the issue tracker on their github for similar problems??

Comment: Segfault errors should be reported to the neovim repository along with a procedure on how to reproduce them and ideally a stacktrace. Make sure to test with the latest release and verify it still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to D. Ben Knoble above. Moving the file from ~/.config/nvim/ftplugins/pandoc.vim to ~/.config/nvim/**after**/ftplugins/pandoc.vim made it work. Not that it explains why it didn't work before.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/7612)

Comment: @jamessan in this case, there was no other answer... I suggested a tip, not a solution—it happened to work for the OP, so they self-answered with their discovered solution.